# seminorm of solutions of Laplace equation

Tags: finite-element

If $u_1$ and $u_2$ are solutions of (weak-form) Laplace equation on a connected domain $\Omega$, with Dirichlet boundary values $u_{\partial\Omega, 1}$ and $u_{\partial\Omega, 2}$, respectively. If $$u_{\partial\Omega,1} \neq u_{\partial\Omega, 2},$$ we know $$\|u_1-u_2\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \neq 0.$$

My question is, for any open set $\tilde{\Omega} \subset \Omega$, is $$\|u_1-u_2\|_{L^2(\tilde{\Omega})} \neq 0 $$ always true?

Comment: Should the last equation contain an equality instead?

Comment: I changed the words, hopefully there's no ambiguity.

Comment: You will want to specify that $\Omega$ is connected because otherwise, if you change the boundary condition on one part of the domain, it doesn't affect the solution on the other part of the domain.

Comment: Also, do you assume that $\tilde\Omega$ is an open subset of $\Omega$? Or could it be just a set of individual points, or a lower-dimensional submanifold?

Comment: @Wolfgang Bangerth You are right, I need $\Omega$ to be connected, and $\tilde{\Omega}$ to be an open subset of the same dimension. Thanks.

Comment: By Laplace equation, do you mean $\Delta u = 0$ (as opposed to the Poisson equation)?

Comment: @user7440 Yes, it's $\Delta u=0$.

Comment: I'm sure I make a mistake but can't you simply take a unit circle as $\Omega$ and take a half-unit circle as subdomain and then let your solutions coincide on the subdomain by  setting sane boundary conditions there and make them different in the ring between the unit and half-unit circles?

Comment: @VorKir I think in that case, the solution in the subdomain (half-unit circle) together with the solution in the ring would generally not be a solution in $\Omega$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us note $w = u_1 - u_2$. We know that $-\Delta w = 0$ in $\Omega$.

Assume that there is $\tilde{\Omega} \subset \Omega$ such that $w = 0$ on $\tilde{\Omega}$ (without any loss of generality, we can assume that $\overline{ \tilde{\Omega} } \subset \Omega$). As $w$ satisfies the Laplace equation, there is no jump for $w$ across the boundary of $\tilde{\Omega}$: $[w]_{|\partial \tilde{\Omega}} = 0$ and similarly for the normal derivative.

So, in $\Omega \backslash \tilde{\Omega}$, $w$ satisfies the Laplace equation and, on $\partial \tilde{\Omega}$, $w$ has a null trace and a null normal derivative.

By a continuation argument (see R. Leis, "Initial boundary value problems in mathematical physics", 1986), $w$ is 0 in $\Omega \backslash \tilde{\Omega}$.

Comment: I don't have access to that book. By the continuation argument, do you mean $u \in C^{\infty}$ at least in $\Omega\setminus\tilde{\Omega}$?

Comment: I mean that w will be zero in a neighborhood of $\partial \tilde{\Omega}$ and, as $-\Delta w = 0$, this neighborhood can grow to cover the whole region $\Omega \backslash \tilde{\Omega}$.

Comment: The argument is sometimes called Holmgren's uniqueness theorem (that is discussed in Hormander, "Linear partial differential equations"). It is also used here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531504/holmgrens-uniqueness-theorem-and-unique-continuation-for-the-schr%c3%b6dinger-equati

Comment: I checked Holmogren's uniqueness theorem, it says the elliptic operator is hypoelliptic, which means $u\in C^{\infty}$. It seems like all those theorems apply to strong form. What if we are talking about weak solution: $u \in H^1_{u_{\partial\Omega}}$
$$\int \nabla v \cdot \nabla u d\Omega = 0, \forall v \in H^1_0$$?

Comment: The function $w$ will be very smooth away from the boundary $\partial \Omega$, as it satisfies $\Delta w = 0$. How regular is $\Omega$?